# MySQL Help with storing data

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a database for a client where I will have an Account and in that account I want to have the post's of that account along with the post's data (likes, comments). How could i store the posts (along with their data) in the database?

Comment: This post is too general, you should be doing database design research on Google.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some links towards some pages that would be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose you have this data to handle (accounts,posts,likes,comments) you should create a different table for each of these 'objects'.So you will have:

```
TABLE accounts (id,name,email..)
TABLE posts (id,title,text,account_id[FK]..)
TABLE likes (id,value,post_id[FK])
TABLE comments (id,tect,datetime,post_id[FK])
```

where the 'id' fields are AUTO-INCREMENT index and the fields followed by the 'FK' are foreign keys.
If you're not sure what a foreing key is give a look here [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html)

try being more detailed next time if you need an answer that goes straight-to-the-point!

Hope it helps